# PHP Mail function taking 60+ seconds to execute (using sendmail)

Tags: php, email, sendmail

So I just moved to a new VPS host and the PHP Mail function basically never ends (although oddly enough it usually sends the email).

I set this in my php.ini:
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t

Anyone have any ideas why this would be taking so long?  I even set a start/end variable and printed the time in between and it's literally 60 seconds.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps it is your hosts anti-spam measure. You should contact your host.

Comment: My best guess would be a misconfiguration in DNS lookups, most likely how sendmail tries to look up its own hostname. This question is much more appropriate for [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com) though.

Comment: That might make sense, I haven't set up the hostname properly.. I checked w/the host I know it's not that

Comment: If you have shell access to the VPS, you could try running sendmail from the command line to send an email. That would narrow down the source of the delay to sendmail itself or PHP.

Comment: Which version of PHP/sendmail are you using? Do you have an example message that you're sending?

Answer (score 2):

Mail functions in php is script are slow but 60 sec is too much. Best way is to insert the mail to be sent in Database and send them via cron later (every 2 min). Using Mail queue technique.